# Getting error while sending a request to events api in exact target

Tags: java, exacttarget

I'm getting the below error response when i'm sending a request to **https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events**   to fire an event in Exact Target

**{
  "message": "Runtime Error. Retry this action. Contact Global Support if the issue persists",
  "errorcode": 30000,
  "documentation": ""
   }**

postman shows it's a bad request 400,i'm not sure what's wrong in the endpoint.
Appreciate your help

Comment: The URL give message "Not Authorized". Are you setting username and password if required??

Comment: hey @SachinSarawgi,i'm sending the request with token as shown in the link   (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm).

Comment: 30000 error code implies you are not providing correct resource please check the url and data ur sending

Comment: @SachinSarawgi- the url and data i'm sending is same as what it is there in the link,except the token.There is no event created in Exact Target as of now from my end .i'm trying to make a request and see the url is correct or not for triggering an event or not